# Is there an iwlist equivalent for Windows (XP or later)?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I'd like to have a quick check on all the WLANs in my reach.

On Linux I'd use `iwlist` from CLI to list available WLANs, but is there an equivalent tool on Windows (I need it on XP and up).

In particular, I need a program that gives me a similar output to:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

But on Windows! And I need it on Windows XP, I know there's a netsh command for Windows Vista/7 (`netsh show wlan` I believe), but as I said, I need that to work on Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
netsh wlan show all
```

If you do in Python:

```
ipconfig = subprocess.Popen(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'all'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I don't need a Python interface.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not need to be command line, [netstumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/2007/04/17/about/) is a great utility for wlans.

Comment: What I meant was a built-in command if possible, and yes, it would be preferably from the shell.